# Rename action in blender 2.8

Tags: actions

I am trying to rename some actions in my scene, but the only way I have found is to go to the `Blender file` in the outliner and modify it there. This is unconvenience because if you have thousands of animations, its not clear to know which one is each.

If I select an object with an animation and I can see the action in the dopesheet or in the graph editor, what should I do to change the name of the action in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 3):

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Left Click**

[image]

In most editors, can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Left Click in name field to rename.  Image example showing graph editor and dope sheet.

Comment: Thank you very much